# Redirect if NO referrer and redirect typein traffic

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to load content from a different page if the user came to the page with NO referrer or if the user types my page in directly.

This is the code I would like to alter to be able to achieve this.

The code below redirects based on if the user has 1 of the IPs listed below, it will load the `fakepage.php`.  I would like to alter this script so it can work if there is NO referrer, or if the user types in my url directly.

```
<?php
$banned = array('56.150.186.229','89.103.221.49');
$userIP = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
if(in_array($userIP,$banned)) {
include_once('fakepage.php');
} else {
include_once('realpage.php');
}
?>
```

I'm trying to make this look as seamless as possible, so the user will not know they were redirected

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get the users ip (you may need another header if you are running behind a proxy or similar. Then check to see if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is empty for your second condition.

```
 $banned = array('56.150.186.229','89.103.221.49');
 $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // likely users ip
 $noReferer = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
 if(in_array($userIP,$banned) or $noReferer) {
   include_once('fakepage.php');
 } else {
   include_once('realpage.php');
 }
```

Comment: so if I understand this correctly, this will display the fake page if they come from a certain IP, type in my url into the url bar directly, and if there is no referrer?

Comment: i they type in the url directly there will be no referer, or if for some other reason if they don't send a referer so we will show the fake pae. Also if they come from an ip listed it will show the fake pae. @JoeBobby